# NullReferenceException в @Scripts.Render после обновления Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, mvc

после обновления bootstrap до последней версии (5.0.1) выдает исключение (ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта) в Views\Shared_Layout. Исключение кидает в строке:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Проверила Views\WebConfig, там System.Web.Optimization на месте. Почему то кидает исключение только с новыми версиями, если откатить до 4.0.0, например, то все работает нормально. В чем может быть дело?

На всякий скриншоты прикреплю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBUL4.png)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Migrating to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/) - в бутстрапе довольно много ломающих изменений. Пока мне не встречались гайды по миграции asp.net с 4-й на 5-ю версию бутстрапа. Может это чем-то поможет: [Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-aspnetmvc) - там описано применение утилиты upgrade-assistant. Возможно, она поможет и bootstrap починить.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло принудительное подключение:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
```

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer